# RPi3 on Sony Bravia HDMI Produces Flickering Lines

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, display, config.txt

After working for a while, and with various distributions and SDs, my Raspberry Pi 3 no longer properly works with my Sony Bravia. With the HDMI inserted it now displays flickering, changing lines. It must be broadcasting the correct video because the colors of the lines represent images that should be displayed while starting up (splash screens, etc). Once booted I can SSH as normal, the Pi is working and on. But the distorted video remains.

The catch is that the HDMI on the Pi works fine on every other monitor and television I've used (just as it worked on this one). The power supply seems fine. I've tried multiple working HDMI wires. Other HDMI devices connected to the TV with the same HDMI and connector work fine (X-Box 360 and Roku).

I've also added the following to /boot/config.txt:

```
gpu_mem_256=128
gpu_mem_512=256
gpu_mem_1024=256
overscan_scale=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
```

This does not work to fix the issue. Once the power goes on and the HDMI is in the RPi3, the lines occur.

2/7 UPDATE: my SD with NOOBs with Libreelec & Raspbian works fine. An SD with Berryboot Loader that contains RetroPie, Kali, and Raspbian Lite is the one acting up on this set (but that SD does work fine on other televisions).

[image: Immediate glitch; will change colors according to the image the video should be displaying]

Comment: I have noticed that different versions of Raspberry Pi, Beagle Bone, Orange Pi and Intel NUC seems to deliver different quality of the HDMI signal. The same cable and monitor give different monitor quality. Test with a different cable, lower the resolution ....

Comment: I tried with different cables but unfortunately the same thing happens (only on this TV set). As for the resolution, on the television in general or within the Pi's settings? UPDATE (will update question): my SD with NOOBs with Libreelec & Raspbian works fine. An SD with Berryboot Loader that contains RetroPie, Kali, and Raspbian Lite is the one acting up on this set (but that SD does work fine on other televisions).

Comment: HDMI has many sub-variants and sub-types. It is generally supposed to auto-detect the greatest common divisor. Sometimes this doesn't happen. Perhaps you should investigate HDMI options in `/boot/config.txt` , for example I would investigate `CONFIG_HDMI_BOOST` to see if there is a signal strength issue.

Comment: I just tried config_hdmi_boost 5 through 11, no change. Also tried commenting out the overscan_scale=1. To test the resolution I also tried hdmi_mode=5, hdmi_mode=16, hdmi_mode=4, and hdmi_mode=19. No change. Could this be a problem with Berryboot and some kind of configuration within it? It works fine on other monitors though, no configurations have been changed. And TV works with other HDMI devices. Will continue to investigate, thanks for the suggestions so far.

Comment: @Interrupt SInce you've eliminated hardware and configuration. It is possible the GPU firmware is outdated or has a bug.  I would verify version of GPU firmware is present, you may try to manually replace firmware with [latest from raspberry](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware) or try to see if an update us available. It is odd for it to work but not all monitors, its a frustrating problem to have.